# Issue when Calling a function from another .py file

Tags: python, function, import

In my intro python class i have a homework assignment that whats us to practice calling functions. The Homework  problem number 2 question can use part of the code from the first question. So in the code of the second question I try importanting the first question file and call on the function inside of it. When i run the code it runs the entire .py from the first question and not just the function i want it to run. Also is it possible to send a variable as a argument into the functions parameter as i tried doing that here. The basic of the homework problem 1 is to create a program that calculates the possible divisors of a number and the second problem is to pick a random positive number and tell if it is a prime number or not.

Question 1 code

```
number = int(input('Enter a number to find divisors'))
numberrange = []
divisors = []
def divisors_in_number(number):

for i in range(number):
    numberrange.append(i)
numberrange.append(number)
numberrange.remove(0)

for i in numberrange:
    x = number % i
    if x == 0:
        divisors.append(i)
divisors_in_number(number)
print("The divisors of " + str(number) + " are ")
print(divisors)
```

Question 2 code

```
 import random
def randomnumber(x,y):
    x = random.randint(x,y)
    return(x)
number = randomnumber(0,999)
print(number)

from Divisors import divisors_in_number
NewDivisors = divisors_in_number(number)
print(NewDivisors)

if                                             #Not finished need to get above part working correctly  
    print('Number is a prime number? True')
else 
    print('Number is a prime number? false')
```

Comment: There is also a package named divisor, so try to rename the file contain question 1, for example, "firstQuest.py", then try to import it again in question 2

Answer (score 0):

In Python, it's common to see the following:

```py
# Defining some function that might be reused later
def my_sum(a, b):
    return a + b

# This will only be True if this file is called directly
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(my_sum(5, 7))
```

So basically, that allows you to import a certain file to reuse its functions without running parts of it that you might not want to.

`__name__` is a special variable that contains the name of the current script, but if it's been called directly, it'll be `"__main__"`, so that's a way of knowing whether that script is being run directly or imported. If it's imported, it's `__name__` won't be `"__main__"`.

Corey Schafer has some pretty good Python tutorials on YouTube, and [here's one exactly about this](https://youtu.be/sugvnHA7ElY).

As for importing something from one file to another, it *should* work fine if they're both on the same directory. As suggested in the comments to your question, try giving the file a less common name, and see if it helps.

For example, if the code I used as an example is stored in a file called `my_script.py`, and I want to use its `my_sum` function in another file that's on the same directory, I could do the following:

```py
from my_script import my_sum

print(my_sum(3, 6))
```

Another point worth mentioning is that, especially in Python, indentation is extremely important. That's what the interpreter uses to know what's part of a function definition, what's part of an `if` block, and so on.

The code you posted on your question has some messy indentation, but I suppose some of it could have happened in the process of copying it to the question. In any case, it's worth double-checking your indentation is correct and consistent.

From what I know, the most "recommended" indentation for Python is 4 spaces, so that's what I usually go with. Other indentations do work, as long as they're kept throughout the entire script. Mixing different forms of indentation in the same script is bound to cause errors.